# C++ linked list/polymorphism not running list function

Tags: c++, list, polymorphism, shapes

I have to make a class Shape with subclasses for specific shapes that find volume. We have to be able to construct the objects and store them in a linked list. I am testing creating one object and am wondering why it does not run my function cout commands. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

class Shape{
public:
    friend class my_list;
    Shape(double a=0,double b=0 ,double c=0):width(a),height(b),length(c){
    }

protected:
    double width;
    double height;
    double length;
    Shape *nextPtr;
};

class Rectangle:public Shape
{
public:
    Rectangle(double a, double b,double c):Shape(a,b,c){
        area = width * length;
    };

private:
    double area;
};

class Circle:public Shape
{
public:
    Circle(double a):Shape(a){
        area = (radius*radius)*3.14;
    }
protected:
    double area;
    double radius;
};

class Triangle:public Shape
{
public:
    Triangle(double a, double b,double c):Shape(a,b,c){
        area = .5*width*length;
    };
protected:
    double area;
};

class Cubic:public Rectangle
{
public:
    Cubic(double a, double b,double c):Rectangle(a,b,c){
        volume = width * length * height;
    };
protected:
    double volume;
};

class Sphere:public Circle
{
public:
    Sphere(double a):Circle(a){
        volume = (width*width*width)*(4/3)*3.14;
    };
protected:
    double volume;
};

class Cone:public Circle{
public:
    Cone(double a, double b):Circle(a){
        height = b;
        volume = 3.14*(width*width)*(height/3);
    };
protected:
    double volume;
};

class my_list{
public:
    my_list();
    ~my_list();

    void add_node(Shape*);
    void print_list();
    Shape* make_node();

private:
    Shape* firstPtr;
    Shape* lastPtr;
};

my_list::my_list():firstPtr(NULL), lastPtr(NULL){}
my_list::~my_list(){}

Shape* my_list::make_node(){
    cout << "What shape would you like to construct?" << endl;
    cout << "\t1. Rectangle" << "\n\t2. Triangle" << "\n\t3. Cirlce" <<
    "\n\t4. Cubic" <<"\n\t5. Sphere" << "\n\t6. Cone" << endl;
    int number; cin >> number; cin.get();

    cout << "Enter width/height/length or radius, or radius/height" << endl;
    double a,b,c; cin >> a; cin>>b; cin>> c;
    switch (number) {
        case 1: {
            Shape *newPtr = new Rectangle(a,b,c);
            return newPtr;
        }

        case 2: {
            Shape *newPtr = new Triangle(a,b,c);
            return newPtr;

        }

        case 3: {
            Shape *newPtr = new Circle(a);
            return newPtr;
        }
        case 4: {
            Shape *newPtr = new Sphere(a);
            return newPtr;
        }
        case 5: {
            Shape *newPtr = new Cubic(a,b,c);
            return newPtr;
        }

        case 6:{
            Shape *newPtr = new Cone(a,b);
            return newPtr;
        }
        default:
               return 0;
    }
}

void my_list::add_node(Shape* new_node){
    if ( firstPtr == NULL ) // empty list
        firstPtr = lastPtr = new_node; // nextPtr  = NULL by default
    else {
        new_node -> nextPtr = firstPtr;
        firstPtr = new_node; // set first pointer to beginning of the list;
    }
}

int main(){
    /*
    while(true) {
        cout << endl << endl << "\tSelect the following options" << endl;
        cout << "\t1. Construct" << "\n\t2. Add" << "\n\t3. Print" <<
        "\n\t4. Quit" << endl;
        cout << "\tSelection:\t";
        int options; cin >> options; cin.get(); // cin leaves newline, cin.get() to cancel it

        switch (options) {
            case 1: //construct function

            case 2: {
              //add function
            }

            case 3:
               //print function



            case 4:
            default: break;
        }
    }
    */

    my_list l1;
    l1.add_node(l1.make_node());
}
```

Comment: Define "why it does not run my function cout commands".

Comment: You're not using runtime polymorphism: it only kicks in for `virtual` functions.  Do some googling / background reading - you'll find scores of sites giving working code for `Shape`-derived classes.

Comment: Your `Shape` class requires a virtual destructor.  Without it, the behavior is undefined if you `delete` a derived Shape object using a Shape pointer.

Comment: Do you see _any_ output from the top of `my_list::make_node()`?
BTW: the member variable of `radius` in your `Circle` class is not initialized. I suspect you wanted to set it to `a`.

Comment: **−1** debug-my-code question.

Answer (score 0):

few pointers :

1. try creating an object of my_list before calling any functions on it .
   like  my_list l1 = new my_list();
2. In switch-case usage use break instead of return. 
   like:

   switch (n){
      case 1: 
         ...
      break;

   case 2: 
         ...
      break;
   }

3.start using an IDE and add break points for debugging.